# Semaphore-like queue in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `can_run`, that can be either 1 or 0, and then I have a queue of functions, that should be run as soon as the variable is switched from `0` to `1` (but only 1 such function at a time).

Right now, what I do is

```
var can_run=1;
function wait_until_can_run(callback) {
    if (can_run==1) {
        callback();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function(){wait_until_can_run(callback)},100);
    }
}

//...somewhere else...

wait_until_can_run( function(){
   can_run=0;
   //start running something
});

//..somewhere else, as a reaction to the task finishing..
can_run=1;
```

It works, however, it doesn't strike me as very efficient to have about 100 timeouts continuously running. Something like semaphore would be handy in here; but in general, semaphores are not really needed in JavaScript.

So, what to use here?

edit: I have written "queue of functions" but as seen here, I don't really care about the order.

Comment: Are you using any libraries like jQuery or Dojo?  They have deferred capabilities that match your usage.

Comment: You need to learn about promises.  See Q, or jQuery's deferreds.

Comment: @karel -- please do not edit questions like that...

Comment: Agree with @Neal, if you want post a self answer with what you would use today. Answering the question inside the question itself isn't a good idea.

Comment: Also @karel I updated my answer to have es6 use. Remember to pick an answer as accepted if it helped you at all :-)

Answer (score 33):

Here is a nice Queue class you can use **without** the use of timeouts:

```
var Queue = (function () {

    Queue.prototype.autorun = true;
    Queue.prototype.running = false;
    Queue.prototype.queue = [];

    function Queue(autorun) {
        if (typeof autorun !== "undefined") {
            this.autorun = autorun;
        }
        this.queue = []; //initialize the queue
    };

    Queue.prototype.add = function (callback) {
        var _this = this;
        //add callback to the queue
        this.queue.push(function () {
            var finished = callback();
            if (typeof finished === "undefined" || finished) {
                //  if callback returns `false`, then you have to 
                //  call `next` somewhere in the callback
                _this.dequeue();
            }
        });

        if (this.autorun && !this.running) {
            // if nothing is running, then start the engines!
            this.dequeue();
        }

        return this; // for chaining fun!
    };

    Queue.prototype.dequeue = function () {
        this.running = false;
        //get the first element off the queue
        var shift = this.queue.shift();
        if (shift) {
            this.running = true;
            shift();
        }
        return shift;
    };

    Queue.prototype.next = Queue.prototype.dequeue;

    return Queue;

})();
```

It can be used like so:

```
// passing false into the constructor makes it so 
// the queue does not start till we tell it to
var q = new Queue(false).add(function () {
    //start running something
}).add(function () {
    //start running something 2
}).add(function () {
    //start running something 3
});

setTimeout(function () {
    // start the queue
    q.next();
}, 2000);
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dUVGX/

---

Updated to use es6 and new es6 Promises:

```
class Queue {  
  constructor(autorun = true, queue = []) {
    this.running = false;
    this.autorun = autorun;
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  add(cb) {
    this.queue.push((value) => {
        const finished = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const callbackResponse = cb(value);

        if (callbackResponse !== false) {
            resolve(callbackResponse);
        } else {
            reject(callbackResponse);
        }
      });

      finished.then(this.dequeue.bind(this), (() => {}));
    });

    if (this.autorun && !this.running) {
        this.dequeue();
    }

    return this;
  }

  dequeue(value) {
    this.running = this.queue.shift();

    if (this.running) {
        this.running(value);
    }

    return this.running;
  }

  get next() {
    return this.dequeue;
  }
}
```

It can be used in the same way:

```
const q = new Queue(false).add(() => {
    console.log('this is a test');

    return {'banana': 42};
}).add((obj) => {
    console.log('test 2', obj);

    return obj.banana;
}).add((number) => {
    console.log('THIS IS A NUMBER', number)
});

// start the sequence
setTimeout(() => q.next(), 2000);
```

Although now this time if the values passed are a promise etc or a value, it gets passed to the next function automatically.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/toefqpsc/

Comment: `add_function` should be `addFunction` or simply `add` or `push`. You could also introduce `unshift` to add functions to the start of the queue.

Comment: @Shmiddty so needy :-P I do not see any issue with naming the fn `add_function`, it all depends on your naming conventions. And yes other methods could be added for other functions, but they are are not necessary for this answer.

Comment: I feel like non camel-case names in javascript are counter-intuitive, since the language itself uses camel-case for everything.

Comment: @Shmiddty Also, it's Crockford's standards, Yahoo's, Google's, Microsoft's and pretty much every single standard I've read.

Comment: The appropriateness of a naming convention is entirely dependent on the language in which you are programming. The end goal is so that you don't have to remember if something is `add_function` or `addFunction`. Since the language does everything in `camelCase`, that is going to be the first thing you try, intuitively.

Comment: If one `dequeue` just finished its first line `this.running = false;` and at this time a new function is added, and it goes to `if (this.autorun && !this.running) ` which is true, so two `dequeue` will run simultaneously? Will this happen? I think the best time to set `running` as false is after you test `shift` as `undefined`.

Comment: @Moon that seems like an edge case. Can you show an example of that happening?

Comment: @Neal I just though that would be a potential bug. I tried to make up an example but just found the `add` call and the `callback`s are running sync-ly, which means that only after the first callback is done, can the second function be added to the queue. So if all the callbacks are sync functions, the queue is meaningless. Eh, forget it. The function queue for async functions are useful.

Comment: @Moon I am so confused. Can you explain? Maybe in chat? http://javascriptroom.com

Comment: After experiencing unexpected behavior with this queue mecanism, I understood that one should be careful to return any error correctly (i.e. try catch) from the callbacks added to the queue. In the current version, if a callback throws, the exception remains invisible unless some message is sent from the reject handler, something like : `finished.then(this.dequeue.bind(this), ((e) => {throw e.error;}));` This means the criteria used to resolve or reject should probably be a bit more informative than a simple boolean about any error occuring. I used a `{error}` object in case of error.

Comment: @Neal What if we have parameters on function calls.

Comment: @SachinPrasad that is what the pass throughs are for.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure the best way to do this in plain JS but many libraries have Deferred implementations which are very useful for this use case.

With jQuery:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var callback = function() { 
    // do stuff
};
dfd.done(callback);  // when the deferred is resolved, invoke the callback, you can chain many callbacks here if needed
dfd.resolve(); // this will invoke your callback when you're ready
```

**EDIT**  One of the nice things about these library supported deferreds are that they are normally compatible with Ajax events, and in turn other Deferred objects so you can create complex chains, trigger events on Ajax complete, or trigger the 'done' callback after multiple conditions are met.  This is of course more advanced functionality, but it's nice to have in your back pocket.

Comment: There's also a standalone lib for deferred's: https://github.com/heavylifters/deferred-js

Comment: I will definitely try this. No offense for @Neal solution, but this seems nicer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other useful answers here, if you don't
need the extras that those solutions provide, then an
[asynchronous semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_semaphore) is straightforward to implement.

It's a lower-level concept than the other options presented
here though, so you may find those to be more convenient for
your needs. Still, I think asynchronous semaphores are worth
knowing about, even if you use higher-level abstractions in
practice.

It looks something like this:

```
var sem = function(f){
    var busy = 0;
    return function(amount){
        busy += amount;
        if(busy === 0){
            f();
        }
    };
};
```

And you invoke it like this:

```
var busy = sem(run_me_asap);
```

`busy` is a function that maintains an internal counter of
asynchronous actions that it is waiting on. When that
internal counter reaches zero, it fires the function
`run_me_asap`, which you supply.

You can increment the internal counter prior to running an
asynchronous action with `busy(1)` and, then the
asynchronous actions is responsible for decrementing the
counter with `busy(-1)` once it is complete. This is how we
can avoid the need for timers. (If you prefer, you could
write `sem` so that it returns an object with `inc` and
`dec` methods instead, like in the Wikipedia article; this
is just how I do it.)

And that's all you have to do to create an asynchronous
semaphore.

Here's an example of it in use. You might define the function
`run_me_asap` as follows.

```
var funcs = [func1, func2, func3 /*, ...*/];
var run_me_asap = function(){
    funcs.forEach(function(func){
        func();
    });
});
```

`funcs` might be the list of functions that you wanted to
run in your question. (Maybe this isn't quite what you want,
but see my 'N.B.' below.)

Then elsewhere:

```
var wait_until_ive_finished = function(){
    busy(1);
    do_something_asynchronously_then_run_callback(function(){
        /* ... */
        busy(-1);
    });
    busy(1);
    do_something_else_asynchronously(function(){
        /* ... */
        busy(-1);
    });
};
```

When both asynchronous operations have completed, `busy`'s
counter will be set to zero, and `run_me_asap` will be
invoked.

**N.B.** How *you* might use asynchronous semaphores depends
on the architecture of your code and your own requirements;
what I've set out may not be exactly what you want. I'm just
trying to show you how they work; the rest is up to you!

And, one word of advice: if you were to use asynchronous
semaphores then I'd recommend that you hide their creation
and the calls to `busy` behind higher-level abstractions so
that you're not littering your application code with
low-level details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm visiting from nine years in the future to tell anyone who finds this thread to look into AsyncIterable and "for await (...)".  I think this promise-based technique would provide an adequate solution.

Here's an example of an AsyncIterable that is essentially a queue of functions as the questioner was looking for.

```js
class AsyncFunctionIterable {

    resolveWaitingPromise = ()=>{};
    functionQueue = [];
    running = false;

    async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        this.running = true;
        while( this.running ) {
            // If the queue is empty, wait for another item to be added.
            if(this.functionQueue.length===0) {
                await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { this.resolveWaitingPromise = resolve } );
                if( !this.running ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            const func = this.functionQueue.shift();
            const value = await func(); // Potentially asynchronous function.
            yield value;
        }
    }

    add( func ) {
        return this.push( func );
    }

    push( func ) {
        this.functionQueue.push( func );
        this.resolveWaitingPromise();
    }

    stop() {
        this.running = false;
        resolveWaitingPromise();
    }

    unshift( func ) {
        this.functionQueue.unshift( func );
        this.resolveWaitingPromise();
    }

}
```

The following is a functional example of a filesystem walker.  Instead of having a function that goes through your disk and builds a large set of data to return with information on all files found on a filesystem, the AsyncFunctionIterator allows you to go file by file with a much smaller memory footprint and almost no wait time before you're able to start processing data.

```js
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");
const FS = require( "fs" );
const Path = require( "path" );


class FileSystemWalker extends EventEmitter {
    basePath = undefined;
    constructor( str ) {
        super();
        this.basePath = str;
    }

    stop() {
        this.emit( "stop" );
    }
    
    /**
     * returns an AsyncIterable which generates {path:string, stats:FS.Stats} objects.
     */
    walk() {
        const queue = new AsyncFunctionIterable();
        this.once( "stop", () => queue.stop() ); 
        queue.push( async () => handlePath( this.basePath ) );
        return queue;

        async function handlePath( curPath ) {
            const stats = await FS.promises.lstat( curPath );
            if( stats.isDirectory() ) {
                let children = await FS.promises.readdir( curPath );
                if( children.length ) {
                    // To keep things in alphabetical order, we'll:
                    // 1: reverse the order 
                    // 2: frontload them on the queue.
                    children = children.reverse(); 
                    for( const child of children ) {
                        queue.unshift( async () => handlePath( Path.resolve( curPath, child ) ) );
                    }
                }
            }
            return { path: curPath, stats };
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Execution by VM begins here.
 */
( async function() {
    const FSWalker = new FileSystemWalker( process.env.HOME );
    setTimeout( () => FSWalker.stop(), 2000 );
    for await ( const file of FSWalker.walk() ) {
        console.log( file.path + ( file.stats.isDirectory() ? Path.sep : "" ) );
    }
} )().then( () => console.log( "DONE" ) ).then( process.exit );
```

NOTE: In other code I have, I've used this process, but instead of having a queue of functions, I've used a single function and a set of file paths.  This lets us work with a much smaller memory footprint, but requires specific code in the AsyncIterator object.  The question was looking for a generic function queue.  The nice thing about what this way of looking at the problem is that a function queue doesn't just allow for one type of computation, rather you can put whatever function you like in it and execute them one-by-one.

Put both code snippets in one file to see the code in work.  I've put a timer in to show an example of stop execution after 2 seconds.