# JS Execute functions in order, while passing the next function as an argument

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to eliminate the "callback pyramid of DOOM" by doing this:

```
$$( //my function
  function(next) { // <- next is the next function
    setTimeout(next,1000); // simple async function
  },

  function(next){ // this function is the previous's function "next" argument
    waitForSomethingAndReturnAValue(next, "I am a parameter!");
  },

  function(aValue){
    console.log("My value is:" + aValue);
  }
);
```

BUT I have been fiddling for about an hour, and my code doesn't work, any help? this is what I got so far:

```
function $$(){
  for (a in arguments){
    arguments[a] = function(){
      arguments[a](arguments[Math.max(-1, Math.min(a+1, arguments.length-1))]);
    };
  }
  arguments[0]();
}
```

Comment: you just want to execute several functions in order? You can do an array with the functions you want and make a function executes first function in array and then deleted it

Comment: Yes but I want it so the function itself executes the next function. see code block #1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Semaphore-like queue in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528749/semaphore-like-queue-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, consider learning about promises instead of rolling your own asynchronousity abstractions :)

Comment: Also, you have an implicit global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
function $$() {
    if (arguments.length <= 0) return;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // convert to array

    arguments[0](function () { $$.apply(null, args.slice(1)); });
}

$$(function(next) { alert("one"); next() }, function (next) { alert("two"); next() });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cz92w/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function $$(){
    var i=0, ret, args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var obj = {
        next: function() {
            ret = args[i++].call(obj, ret);
        }
    };
    obj.next();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$$(
    function() {
        console.log(Date() + ' - Function 1');
        setTimeout(this.next, 1e3); // simple async function
    },
    function(){
        console.log(Date() + ' - Function 2');
        return waitForSomethingAndReturnAValue(this.next, "I am a parameter!");
    },
    function(aValue){
        console.log(Date() + ' - Function 3');
        console.log("My value is:" + aValue);
    }
);
function waitForSomethingAndReturnAValue(callback, param) {
    setTimeout(callback, 2e3);
    return param + param;
}
```

Basically, the returned value in each function is passed as the argument to the next one. And the reference to the next function is `this.next`.