# Will injected JS code finish before removing

Tags: javascript, html

Is it guaranteed that this code

```
function runEmbeddedJSInPageEnvironment(code) {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.type = 'text/javascript';
  e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(e);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}

runEmbeddedJSInPageEnvironment("$('#someform').off('submit');");
```

will wait for the code passed to the `runEmbeddedJSInPageEnvironment` to finish first, and only then remove it from the page by calling `removeChild` function?

Or can it be removed before this code finished to execute?

Comment: I think it depends on browsers

Comment: better be sure and add `scr.onload` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293367/how-to-detect-if-javascript-files-are-loaded (and remove child afterwards)

Comment: I would use the queue as in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899102/how-do-i-store-javascript-functions-in-a-queue-for-them-to-be-executed-eventuall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to HTML5 the code will run before removing the `script` element.

When you insert it into the document, it's immediately [prepared](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script):

> When a [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element that is not marked as being
>   ["parser-inserted"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#parser-inserted) experiences one of the events listed in the
>   following list, the user agent must synchronously [prepare](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script) the
>   [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element:
>
> - The [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element gets [inserted into a document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#insert-an-element-into-a-document), at the time the [node is inserted](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#nodes-are-inserted) according to the DOM, after any
>     other [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) elements inserted at the same time that are
>     earlier in the [`Document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) in [tree order](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#tree-order).

At step 15 of the [prepare a script](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script) algorithm, since the `script` doesn't have a [`src`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute and has not been flagged as ["parser inserted"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#parser-inserted), your case would be the last one:

> Otherwise: The user agent must immediately [execute the script
>   block](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#execute-the-script-block), even if other scripts are already executing.

But of course, if that script has asynchronous code like `setTimeout`, that will be postponed.