# how to queue functions using an array when functions are called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding in JavaScript and was wondering how I would go about queueing functions in an array when called until a execute function is called causing the rest of them to be calculated.

the code that I have for something like this and was just wondering if it would work.

```
addNegationTask(x)
{
   this.value = this.value * -1
   // this adds the equation to the array
   this.tasks.push(x => value * -1)
   return this.value;
}
```

I have other functions that follow a simular route, any answers on the matter would be greatly apriciacted.

Comment: hello you can find a useful help in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899102/how-do-i-store-javascript-functions-in-a-queue-for-them-to-be-executed-eventuall)

Comment: @kemicofa sorry my bad, I've deleted my comment

Comment: what do you mean by **anonymous**?

Comment: I'm not sure its something that is being asked for on the brief that I have been given for this task.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `x` argument to `addNegationTask`? You never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the assignment in the callback function.

```
addNegationTask()
{
   // this adds the equation to the array
   this.tasks.push(() => this.value *= -1)
}
```

I've removed the `x` argument, since it's not used for anything.